# How can I retrieve the ObserableCollection Object Passed, to be used in the SecondPage

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

Template10 Hamburger. How do I retrieve the Object to be used in the SecondPage.
what would be the best way to achieve this.

I have tried to convert Object to a new collection but get this error:
cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

MainPageViewModel.cs has a ObservableCollection ScoreData.

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase  
   public ObservableCollection<string> ScoreData { get; set; }  

   public MainPageViewModel()
    {List<string> Data = new List<string>();
        Data.Add("10");
        Data.Add("5");
        ScoreData = new ObservableCollection<string>(Data);
```

and I pass it to SecondPage with navigationService

```
    {NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SecondPage), ScoreData);}
```

SecondPageViewModel.cs

```
   public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode,
        IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
    {
        Value = (suspensionState.ContainsKey(nameof(Value)))
            ? suspensionState[nameof(Value)]?.ToString() : parameter?.ToString();
        await Task.CompletedTask;


        // ERROR
        //cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' 
        ObservableCollection<string> ScoreData1 = new ObservableCollection<string> (parameter);
    }
```

The Object is there with the items, I cant figure out how to use the object items in the SecondPage.xaml Textbox's.
Trying to create a new observablecollection to do this gives me the error show above.

```
    Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.ScoreData1[0], Mode=OneWay}" />
    Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.ScoreData1[1], Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Try casting parameter to observablecollection before using it.

Comment: I'm Learning Visual Studio as a hobby. If I knew how to do that I would.

Comment: Try doing `var coll = parameter as IEnumerable<string>;` and use `coll` to create observablecollection. You hobby also should include learning basics of programming languages by simple examples then complex applications.

Comment: coll returns Null and the ScoreData1 throws a exception

Comment: Tried various methods without success. Here is my Code : (https://github.com/Static-SC/Pass-Collection-To-Second-Page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       try {
            var items=parameter as IEnumerable<Score>;
            foreach(var item in items)
            {
                _score.Add(item);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to get you going:

```
public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
{

    if (suspensionState.ContainsKey(nameof(Value)))
    {
        Value = suspensionState[nameof(Value)]?.ToString();
    }
    else if (parameter != null)
    {
        if (parameter is string)
        {
            Value = parameter?.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            var coll = parameter as IEnumerable<string>;
        }
    }
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This can be simplified and you can edit to fit your needs. Basically: this code accepts either a string or a collection of strings, if you know that it will always be a collection you can simplify it. Also this example does not implement properly the resume from suspension state but it gives you an idea how to do this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: coll still returns null. I think I need to define the object "parameter", and if so that's where I'm getting stuck.. At a breakpoint : value= "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[ScoreBoardt10V3.Models.Score]" and the "parameter" objects is holding the values looking like a index, which is correct, but I cant extract those values.